# How to format the writing of python output in ordered column-wise?

Tags: python-3.x, format

I am looking for a way to write the text mentioned below,

```
Step:   0       ID: [291, 339, 377, 441]     Std: 0.1379
Step:   0       ID: [166, 207, 365, 424]     Std: 0.2927
Step:   0       ID: [401, 418, 443]      Std: 0.0997
Step:   0       ID: [160, 170, 222, 394]     Std: 0.2062
Step:   0       ID: [163, 175, 261]      Std: 0.0303
```

in a format similar to

```
Step:   0       ID: [291, 339, 377, 441]     Std: 0.1379
Step:   0       ID: [166, 207, 365, 424]     Std: 0.2927
Step:   0       ID: [401, 418, 443]          Std: 0.0997
Step:   0       ID: [160, 170, 222, 394]     Std: 0.2062
Step:   0       ID: [163, 175, 261]          Std: 0.0303
```

using command alike

```
file.write(f' Step: {step}   ID: {ids}  Std: {stds}').
```

Is there any way to achieve so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the variables you used so I'm going to assume that `ids` is a list. Python includes a [string formatting mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) with which you can align values to a fixed width. This doesn't work with lists directly so you have to convert the list to a string first:

```py
file.write(f' Step: {step}   ID: {str(ids):25}  Std: {stds}').
```

The above ensures that the output of `str(ids)` is 25 characters long.

Comment: Thanks it works, indeed ids is a list.

Comment: @Raghvender I'm glad to hear that! If I solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted to complete the Q&A cycle and mark the issue as resolved for others.